# Error in Syntax for Inserting values into a MySQL db through Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert values from an API into a mysql database but I am running into an error when trying to insert the values

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO DynamicBikeData(AvailableBike, Capacity, Status, Location) VALUES(31' at line 2

I have included by code below, I have tried formatting the sql statement multiple ways but no change in the error

```
import mysql.connector
import requests
import json


#Connect to MySQLServer
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="*********"
)

#Create DB if not already exists
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
try:
    mycursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE comp30830project")
    mycursor.execute("use comp30830project; CREATE TABLE DynamicBikeData (AvailableBike INT, Capacity INT, Status VARCHAR(255),Location VARCHAR(255))")
except:
    print("DataBase already exists")


#Dublin Bikes Data Pull
r = requests.get("https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations",
params={"apiKey":'**************',
"contract": "dublin"})
(json.loads(r.text))

response = requests.get("https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations/42?apiKey=***********")
data = response.text
BikeData = json.loads(data)

for i in range(1,43):
    response = requests.get(f"https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations/{i}?apiKey=****************&contract=dublin")
    data = response.text
    data = json.loads(data)
    availableBikes = data['available_bikes']
    location = f"{data['position']['lat']}{data['position']['lng']}"
    capacity = data['bike_stands']
    status = data['status']

    sql = f"""
    USE comp30830project 
    INSERT INTO DynamicBikeData (AvailableBike, Capacity, Status, Location) VALUES ({availableBikes},{capacity},{status},{location});"""

    mycursor.execute(sql)
    mydb.commit()
```

EDIT:
I have also tried a second way of formatting the sql, still producing this result

DataBase already exists
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 608, in cmd_query
self._cmysql.query(
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO DynamicBikeData (AvailableBike, Capacity, Status, Location) VALUES (' at line 2

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/eoin/Desktop/COMP30830Project/CreateDBandAddData.py", line 45, in 
mycursor.execute(sql,values)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 330, in execute
result = self._cnx.cmd_query(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 616, in cmd_query
raise get_mysql_exception(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO DynamicBikeData (AvailableBike, Capacity, Status, Location) VALUES (' at line 2

Comment: You're missing a `;` after the `USE ...` statement in the `INSERT` line. Also, that's not the best way to work with DB connections. Check the documentation and examples that is available for mysql.connector

Comment: Tried that, not getting the syntax error anymore but instead getting one like this "mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2014 (HY000): Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using f-strings try inserting data like this,

```py
sql = """
USE comp30830project 
INSERT INTO DynamicBikeData (AvailableBike, Capacity, Status, Location) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s);"""
values = (availableBikes, capacity, status, location)
mycursor.execute(sql,values)
```

This should help avoid any error. If You're still facing same error kindly provide a detailed log also check if all variables returned by the API have values in it!

Comment: Yep still receiving an error.   I have edited the question to show it. I have checked and all the variables have data

Comment: @user916750 Then you can try running those two statements seperately! You could also specify the database name to connect to where you're creating the database connection object! You don't have to run that ```use database``` statement everytime

Comment: @user916750 Also note that you are running multiple statements using execute function which is made to run only single statement. If you need to run multiple statements use the the ```multi=True``` argument or just run single statement. Reference : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html